# How does module resolution in TypeScript work for global values (i.e. describe)?

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, jestjs, cypress

While using jest on its own the corresponding typescript definitions got detected right after installing `@types/jest`.

I then started to implement integration tests with cypress. Since cypress is using mocha, I now incorrectly see references of mocha type definitions inside my jest tests. In fact, a number of overlapping type definitions are detected. For instance, `describe` seems to be defined in a number of files. I even tried to implement my own typing for `describe` pointing to jest. Unfortunately, every single time **mocha** "wins".

How can I specify the order of precedence when multiple definitions are detected by the typescript compiler?

[image: multiple typescript definitions for describe]

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [ "dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext" ],
        "types": [ "jest", "mocha" ],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "preserve"
    },
    "include": [ "src/**/*" ]
}
```

However, I also tried the following:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [ "dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext" ],
        "typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@types", "./src/types" ],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": false,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "preserve"
    },
    "include": [ "src/**/*" ]
}
```

In both cases **mocha** is being chosen. How can I switch the type for "describe & co." to **jest**?

Comment: It seems like `import 'jest'` on top of a test file is a feasible workaround. Still looking for a proper solution. So if anyone knows how to deal with this, please share :)

Comment: If you put your integration tests and unit tests in separate folders you can give each a tsconfig file that extends the base and then use this path mapping to null trick to erase the type definitions for the library you don't want (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17042).

Comment: Hi @Pace, thanks for the pointer. I have all my integration tests in a separate folder, namely `cypress/integration/**/*.spec.tsx`. The integration tests should resolve to mocha/chai. On the other hand, the unit tests are all located under `src/**/*.test.tsx` and should resolve to jest. Following your approach I now created a separate `tsconfig.json` under `cypress/tsconfig.json`. That config extends from the root level tsconfig and on top of it has **paths mapping** set to `"paths": { "jest": ["./types/jest"] }`. It still only resovles to **mocha** for both unit and integration tests.

Comment: Hmm, my suggestion wasn't to add the jest types to the jest tests but to remove the mocha types from the jest tests.  Typescript will automatically load all types from `node_modules/@types` so unless you want to blacklist that entire folder (which would mean painfully whitelisting each library) you have to use this trick to blacklist `mocha` by redirecting `mocha` to an empty `.d.ts` file that has no content.  You could also do this with multiple `package.json` but NPM doesn't support that case well.  Or you could wait for [this feature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18588)

Comment: `paths` should be an option

Comment: @soosap do you have compilation errors like "Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: describe" ?

Comment: Type resoving inside IDE can be different from type resolving of launched compiler.

Comment: This isn't really module resolution. Also, paths will definitely not help.

Answer (score 2):

CompilerOptions.types allow you to restrict the typings you want to be available in the scope(folder)

You can try the following:
Create a top level tsconfig.json with
CompilerOptions.types = []

Inside test folder create tsconfig.json and choose jest typings
CompilerOptions.types = ['jest']

Similarly inside integration folder, create tsconfig.json and choose mocha typings
CompilerOptions.types = ['mocha']