# Multiple Typescript typing files both export 'expect' to global

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typescript-typings, cypress

We have an Angular project in VS Code that has both cypress and jest installed for tests. The typings for both these packages declare the expect:

jest index.d.ts:

```
declare const expect: jest.Expect;
```

cypress index.d.ts:

```
// Cypress adds chai expect and assert to global
declare var expect: Chai.ExpectStatic
```

cypress and jest work, the problem is code intellisense seems to randomly fail to resolve the expect method in jest tests. I've tried to move the expect into a namespace but then I get this error: *A 'declare' modifier cannot be used in an already ambient context.* Renaming one of the declarations would work to make it appears ok in intellisense but would fail when running the tests.

How can I get it so VS code intellisense recognizes the correct *expect* based on if it's a cypress test or jest?

Comment: I provided a crude solution to this problem on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56149741/how-does-module-resolution-in-typescript-work-for-global-values-i-e-describe

I tried offering a bounty on that question to get a better answer but none turned up. :(

Comment: @Pace Thanks for linking that, I don't know why google didn't find that. We put exclude: "cypress" in the top tsconfig.json. This prevents the cypress types being brought into scope where our jest tests exist but both cypress and jest still run.